# SwipeRefreshLayout block android.wiget.swith from dragging

Tags: java, android, android-studio, switch-statement, swiperefreshlayout

I have an activity and 10 fragments which I draw on activity. All fragments on activity need to have "drag to refresh". I add Swipe Refresh Layout to create it. Now when I click on the switch, all is fine; but when I try to drag it from one stage to another, swipe to refresh appears, and the switch is just staying in the same position. So how can I block the refreshing of the swipe refresh layout on time when the user drags the switch from one position to another?

I tried to make it like this:

```
    onOffSwitchSettings.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But how can I turn it on after?

Comment: I think you should use`     `((MainActivity)getActivity()).swipeContainer.setEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 0):

According to `SwipeRefreshLayout` reference:

> The `SwipeRefreshLayout` will notify the listener each and every time
>   the gesture is completed again; the listener is responsible for
>   correctly determining when to actually initiate a refresh of its
>   content. If the listener determines there should not be a refresh, it
>   must call `setRefreshing(false)` to cancel any visual indication of a
>   refresh. If an activity wishes to show just the progress animation, it
>   should call `setRefreshing(true)`. **To disable the gesture and progress
>   animation, call `setEnabled(false)` on the view.**

You've forgotten to use `((MainActivity)getActivity()).swipeContainer.setEnabled(fals‌​e)` method.

Another problem is that using above you're going to disable `SRL` permanently, so you need to enable it again when the action is right, I mean there's no more dragging.

Hope it will help